# Duplicating zeroes in an array making room by shifting letters

Tags: python

I'm working on a problem which would take this input:

```
[1, 0, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5, 0]
```

And output this:

```
[1, 0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4]
```

My function detects zeroes and when a zero is the i-th element of the list, `i+1` also becomes a zero and the rest of the list is shifted to make room for it. The elements at the end of the list get pushed out to make room.

I was able to do it with two `for` loops, but that has `O(n^2)`, and I want to do it in `O(n)`. I came up with this:

```
new = [0] * len(arr)
zeroes = 0
d = 0
```

I create a second list of zeroes, `zeroes` counts the list of zeroes and `d` is the index to copy for the second list. The array I use is an input into the function and named `arr`.

First I count zeroes:

```
for i in range(len(arr)):
    if arr[i] == 0:
        zeroes+=1
```

Then I copy. I check by index the value is zero, and if it is, I skip the d-th and d+1-th element.

```
for i in range(len(arr)-zeroes):
    if arr[i] == 0:
        d+=1
    else:
        new[d] = arr[i]
    d+=1
```

However for:

```
[1, 0, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5, 0]
```

The output is:

```
[1, 0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0]
```

I'm not sure why the last element doesn't change.

Comment: Because you're only looping `range(len(arr)-zeroes)` times, hence the last values aren't set

Comment: @yatu that's what I thought but if I change to (len(arr)-zeroes+1) it doesn't work for lists with no zeroes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simpler solution which is still O(n):

```
a = [1,0,2,3,0,4,5,0]
b = []
for i in a:
    b.append(i)
    if i == 0:
        b.append(0)
b = b[:len(a)]
```

The value of b would be

```
[1, 0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4]
```